# Tick mark text direction in R

Tags: r, plot

I am probably overlooking something obvious but then maybe someone else will too.

I'm using a lot of ticks on the x-axis in an R plot.
I have shrunk the margin text to make room (using `cex.axis`) but I want more and it would be better if I could make the text vertical.

Comment: In answer to you question about searching. Try using r-project in the search list:https://www.google.com/search?q=axis+label+orientation+r-project&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: It depends upon what you are plotting, but sometimes it is better to swap your x and y axes so that all those labels can have horizontal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands will make the x-axis text vertical:

```
##The numbers next to the tick marks
par(las=3)
plot(x=1:10, y=1:10, xlab="")

##The x-axis label
mtext("sfdf", 1, las=3, adj=3)
```

Comment: Actually, `las=2` makes the axis labels always perpendicular to the axis.  `las=3` makes them vertical.

Comment: Great! Thanx! Why did I have a hard time googling it?